# Need a good non-graphing calculus calculator that can derive and integrate

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, calculator

It's my 3rd time going through Calculus II and I want to pass this class already.  I'm not trying to cheat I just see people with fancy calculators and I have never even used a calculator on tests before.

I just want to shorten the time it takes to compute fractions, double check my derivatives and antiderivatives, and speed up my test taking in general.  One that could do limits and other stuff like that would be cool too.

Any little known programs worth mentioning? I'd love to have the step-by-step derivative/integral solver

Comment: I have seen people with non-graphing calculators that can at least solve definite integrals.  I just want to find a good one to buy

Comment: I recommend the (non-graphing) Casio FX-115ES; I believe it can do all those things. I'm sure TI has an equivalent too.

Comment: that Casio mentioned looks exactly like the type of device Im looking for

Comment: If the issue isn't tests, then why do you care that it not be a graphing calculator?  Graphing is pretty useful, not to mention the larger screen and possibility of displayed equations.

Comment: Another good Casio that includes graphing is the FX-9750 GII.

Answer (score 6):

A calculator is very unlikely to solve your problems for you. Having taught for a lot of years now, I set up tests so that they measure student's *understanding*'not the tools they happen to have at hand.

Concentrate on *understanding* the subject matter. Yes, that means studying to understand the subject matter after each class, doing exercises, checking other material (lecture notes, web, ...). Sorry, there is no royal road.

Comment: Spot on. I'm an engineering student, and I've seen plenty of powerful calculators floating around. Most of my classmates have those TI-84's (hate em), and a number are going for various versions of the Nspire (better, but lousy). I use a Casio CFX-9850G (first graphing calculator with a color screen), and it's pretty simple. Does all I need it to. Anecdotally, I've noticed that the more powerful calculator someone has, the worse they generally do, because they rely on the calculator to do their thinking for them. One of my buddies runs a TI-36 (scientific) and does just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The calculator may not solve your problems but the casio fx991ES plus is very useful for checking your answers. It only does definite integrals and derivatives and is fairly cheap to buy

Answer (score 0):

The best calculator, in my opinion, is the TI Voyage 200.  Besides Integration and Derivatives displayed in Pretty Print, it even does some Differential Equations.

See here:

[http://www.amazon.com/Texas-Instruments-Voyage-200-Calculator/dp/B00006D2Q1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006D2Q1)

Comment: you're a beauty.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the Casio Fx991es Fx, would be great for *double checking* your answers (it can do integrals between 2 points and derivatives evaluated at points, which is all you really need in calculus). However, I believe you should be focusing a lot on learning the content and understanding the motivations behind the various things you're doing in calculus.

All the best :)